# What do "mention", "promotion", and "situation within your promotion" mean in this paragraph describing a CV?

Tags: cv

I am applying for an Eiffel scholarship, and my school required me to send a CV as follows:

> CV outlining the following information: **mention**, rank of classification, **situation within your promotion**, number of students in the **promotion**, diplomas with indication of specialty, date of graduation, **mentions**/honors and final marks certified by the institution.

I could not understand what do they actually mean or refer to. I have emailed the Coordinator, but have not received her reply.

Please help me correctly understand these terms! Thank you so much!

Comment: Is this an email directly to you? A website? If this is a translation, and you have access to the original, posting that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Acccumulation, this is from an email sent to me.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This sounds like a bad translation from French (and it's not unlikely that the coordinator has no clue how to explain what these terms mean).

The French "*promotion*" means "promotion", but also "class" or "cohort". "*Mention très bien*" is an exam passed with "distinction". "*Situation*" means "situation" but also "position". So what they probably want is:

> CV outlining the following information: **exams passed with distinction**, rank of classification, **position** within your **class/year/cohort**, number of students in the **class/year/cohort**, diplomas with indication of specialty, date of graduation, **any special distinction/honors** and final marks certified by the institution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87264/discussion-on-answer-by-henning-what-do-mention-promotion-and-situation-w).